# How to add reset time on click submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all below code working fine , and any one tel me how could i add reset delay time  like 3 second  ?

i have attached original form that i want impediment this function , what i all need to do is whenever someone hit the submit button , button should change value for "please wait .. " and reset in 3 second value of submit .. that all i want ..  and do not refresh page

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please wait...';this.form.submit();"/>
```

```html
   <form class="sTitan-extra" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="sTitan-name" placeholder="Name*" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="sTitan-phone" placeholder="Phone Number*" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="sTitan-email" placeholder="Email Address*" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="street">Street Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="street" id="sTitan-street" placeholder="Street Address*" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="minis">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="state">State</label>
                            <input type="text" name="state" id="sTitan-state" placeholder="State*" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" id="sTitan-zip" placeholder="Zip*" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="message">Description</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="sTitan-message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Describe your problem"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="but" value="Submit">

                    <p class="little-text">* Required fields</p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="response">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/dist/img/hi5.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="the-content">
                    <p><strong>Thank you <span class="name"></span>!</strong></p>
                    <p>Your request has been submited succesfully, we will send you a confirmation email shortly.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="close"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Delay the submission using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and return false from the inline code.

Comment: `<input type="submit" onclick="this.value='Wait!';setTimeout(()=>this.form.submit(), 3000);return false;">` is the simplest way, but I'd strongly recommend you to use mplungjan's answer.

Comment: i just update on post , can you please take look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need button
2. inline event handling is not recommended
3. If the form target is somewhere else than the page, you can reset the button text - if not, then no need to reset the text since the page is reloaded

Code you need in your page

You do NOT need jQuery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault(); // if it is NOT a button but a submit
        const but = this;
        but.disabled = true;
        but.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        but.value = 'Sending, please wait...';
        // but.form.submit(); // move this outside the timeout to submit immediately     
        setTimeout(function() {
          but.disabled = false;
          but.value = "Submit";
          but.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        }, 3000);
      })
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <form action="https://google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="q" /><input type="button" id="but" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[**External Working example**](https://plungjan.name/SO/testsub.html)

The example below will not actually open a new tab here since _blank is not allowed in a stack snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const but = this;
  but.disabled = true;
  but.value = 'Sending, please wait...';
  but.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("q").select();
    but.disabled = false;
    but.value = "Submit";
    but.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }, 3000);
})
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" /><input type="submit" id="but" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220145/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-how-to-add-reset-time-on-click-submit-button).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, after 3 seconds, set disabled to false, you could use `setTimeout()` with a 3000ms delay:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please wait...';setTimeout(() => { this.disabled=false; this.value = 'submit' },3000);this.form.submit();"/>
```

Comment: That will not work. The form will submit and if the page is still around, it will try to submit again

Comment: Thank you , Yes its working , but it not reset value back to "submit"

Comment: @GayanFernando Updated the answer. Basically you just tuck that into the setTimeout too.

Comment: @mplungjan Only if it is a submit that causes the page to change. Many submits are intercepted by JS and handled with AJAX so the page doesn't leave. Based on the question, that's the situation I inferred they had.

Comment: the form it self have validate function already .. but just want avoid multiple hits on button so button value must need back to "Submit" is there way to do it ?

Comment: `this.form.submit()` will bypass submit event handlers