# How to convert in to call Class from ID in Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

currently i have this code

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault(); // if it is NOT a button but a submit
        const but = this;
        but.disabled = true;
        but.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        but.value = 'Sending, please wait...';
        // but.form.submit(); // move this outside the timeout to submit immediately     
        setTimeout(function() {
          but.disabled = false;
          but.value = "Submit";
          but.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        }, 6000);
      })
    })
  </script>
```

`<form>     <input type="submit" id="but" class="but" value="Submit">    </form>`

in this script it call ID .. but i need call class . how can i call class name instead of ID ?

This is how its successfully submit data look like .. when ever i add script form submit stop working

```
under 10
site.js:694 successful
site.js:695 day 6 month 9 year2020day 6 month 9 year2020stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [customerType] => Residential
            [job] => 
            [id] => 94784610
            [externalId] => 1ed7j8jo-ycuu-jet7-crsat04aibwd
            [source] => website
            [createdOn] => 2020-08-22T05:23:10.7964627Z
            [active] => 1
            [start] => 2020-10-06T16:00:00Z
            [summary] => plumbing, this is test 
            [address] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [street] => B11 4/1 soysapura
                    [unit] => 
                    [country] => United States
                    [city] => 
                    [state] => western
                    [zip] => 92123
                    [streetAddress] => B11 4/1 soysapura
                )

            [customer] => Gavin Pulsingay
            [contacts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [active] => 1
                            [modifiedOn] => 2020-08-22T05:23:10.7973361Z
                            [id] => 94784611
                            [type] => Email
                            [value] => gamesubzero@gmail.com
                            [memo] => 
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [active] => 1
                            [modifiedOn] => 2020-08-22T05:23:10.7977629Z
                            [id] => 94784612
                            [type] => Phone
                            [value] => 771766128
                            [memo] => 
                        )

                )

            [isFirstTimeClient] => 
            [uploadedImages] => Array
                (
                )

            [isSendConfirmationEmail] => 1
            [businessUnitId] => 
            [status] => New
            [agentTag] => Power Digital Marketing
            [dismissingReason] => 
        )

)
```

This is how its successfully submit data look like .. when ever i add script form submit stop working

Comment: your submit input doesn't need any ID, you just have to use the submit event on the form element

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? your question is unclear

Comment: Deleted my answer since i am not sure what OP is talking about here. Provided multiple working solution to the actual question in my answer - BUT OP has different issues to what was posted initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document as a NodeList object.

`addEventListener()` adds a Listener to one element.

So after `document.getElementsByClassName("but")` we added `[0]` so that it adds listener to the first element of NodeList object.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("but")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault(); // if it is NOT a button but a submit
        const but = this;
        but.disabled = true;
        but.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        but.value = 'Sending, please wait...';
        // but.form.submit(); // move this outside the timeout to submit immediately     
        setTimeout(function() {
          but.disabled = false;
          but.value = "Submit";
          but.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        }, 6000);
      })
    })
```

```html
<form>     <input type="submit" id="but" class="but" value="Submit">    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you its working , but whenever i add ID or class submitting got faild  in debug tab showing "outside invalid time" do you have any idea ?

Comment: Yes its on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504407/how-to-add-reset-time-on-click-submit-button?noredirect=1#comment112300866_63504407